# Smoothstate js keeps reloading scripts on repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, smoothstate.js

I'm using smoothstate js for changing pages via ajax and when I click on a link, the page loads successfully and the plugin works, however, it calls my js scripts over and over again and eventually crashes the browser. What could be causing this? How do I exclude my js?[image]

I'm using smoothstate in it's very basic form. And if I remove this snippet from my code, the crazy script loading stops and everything works fine.

```
;(function ($) {
$('#ajaxcontainer-outer').smoothState();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What makes you think that this plugin calls your scripts over and over? I don't see anything in your example or otherwise that indicates this.

Comment: Look at temp.js in the screenshot for example, it gets loaded multiple times. When I remove the '$('#ajaxcontainer-outer').smoothState();' code, it doesn't do this.